# How to expand keys in flunetd with logs in sorted way (latest logs should be on top)

Tags: kubernetes, logging, configuration, fluentd, efk

I'm using EFK stack.

My flunetd configuration is:

```xml
<parse>
    @type multi_format
    <pattern>
      format json
      time_key time
      time_type string
      time_format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ"
      keep_time_key true
    </pattern>
    <pattern>
      format regexp
      expression /^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr)( (.))? (?<log>.*)$/
      time_format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ'
      keep_time_key true
    </pattern>
  </parse>
  emit_unmatched_lines true
</source>
```

Logs in Kibana:

[image: kibana logs]

My requirement is it should show like:

```
log.level info
log.ts    2022-02-28T17:51:16.483554867Z
```

and so on.

Also logs are not sorted means latest logs are at bottom for convenience needs to be on top in Kibana.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the log attribute with a JSON parser like

```
<filter **>
  @type parser
  key_name log
  format json
  reserve_data true
</filter>
```